# No implicit conversion from nil to integer

Tags: ruby, implicit-conversion

I have an array of strings created from taking html and using the split function.  I am trying to iterate through it with:

```
html_array.each do |line|
    ...
end
```

I can `puts` the index of a string within each `line` with `puts line.index('text')`, and I can `puts` the character at an index with `puts line[17]` (neither of which print nil), but when I combine the two into one command like

```
puts line[line.index('text')]
```

it gives me the error:

```
no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
```

Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong?  I am new to programming and ruby btw.

Comment: use `p`, not `puts`: `html_array.each { |line| p line.index 'text' }` you probably have lines that don't match. You should also not parse HTML with the `split` function. Try [Nokogiri](http://rubygems.org/gems/nokogiri) instead.

Answer (score 4):

`line.index('text')` is returning `nil` at some point, because the string "text" can't be found in the line. You are then attempting to access `line[nil]`, which is an invalid array index.

Something like this might be better:

```
index = line.index('text')
if index.nil?
  puts "Text not found"
else
  puts line[index]
end
```

This will check to see if the index of the string is nil before attempting to use it (and will alert you if the line did not contain the string).

Comment: I got it to work with basically the same thing: puts line[line.index("text")] if line.index("text")

Answer (score 0):

Just to track down if there is an error in some of your lines, try:

```
html_array.each do |line|
  puts (line[line.index('text')] rescue "nil")
end
```

That will print a "nil" for every line there is an error.   I suspect that 'text' does not occur in every line.  Could you share the bigger picture of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: "text" did in fact not occur in every line.  It was in all of them but the first, but I didn't realize that at first.  Using rescure didn't work, but I got it to work with puts line[line.index("text")] if line.index("text")

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily like below:

```
   html_array.each do |line|
        if line.index("Text").present?
          puts line[line.index("Text")]
        end
    end
```