# "no implicit conversion from nil to integer"

Tags: ruby

I'm doing my first program, a simple to-do list. I want it to let me type a number, and delete the corresponding item from the list.

Every time though, I get "no implicit conversion from nil to integer". I can't seem to work it out. Any ideas?

```
$list = Array.new

def mainmethod
  puts "Enter new item, or type 'view' to view the list, 'delete' to delete items"
  input = gets.chomp

  if input.downcase == "view"
    puts "Your to do list is as follows:"
    puts $list

  elsif input.downcase == "delete"
    puts "Which item would you like to delete? (Enter a number)"
    deletenumber = gets.chomp.to_i
    deletenumber-=1
    delete_list = [deletenumber]
    delete_list.each do |del|
      $list.delete_at($list.index(del))
    end

  else
    $list << input
    puts "Added to list!"
  end
end

loop { mainmethod }
```

Comment: Searching for this error message should have given you a lot of duplicate answers on StackOverflow. See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12361869/no-implicit-conversion-from-nil-to-integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at for the proper way of using `Array#delete_at`.

What you do is calling `#index` with a number that your array does not contain. Therefore `$list.index(del)` will return `nil` and the call to `#delete_at` will fail.

What you need to do is `$list.delete_at(del)`.

Answer (score 1):

The error `TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer` happens when you try to access an element of an array using `nil` as the index. In your case it looks like `delete_at` is being passed nil:

```
[ 1, 2, 3 ].delete_at(nil)
# => TypeError: no implicit conversion from nil to integer
```